# Conditions of Euler Product

Tags: convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, euler-product

We know that if the infinite sum of a multiplicative function is absolute convergent, then the sum can be expressed as infinite product and the infinite product is absolutely convergent. Does there exists a multiplicative function such that the infinite sum is divergent, yet its Euler product is still absolute convergent?

Thanks a lot